# Any idea if a 2/0 3C teck cable will have fitment issues through a 1-1/2" Metal LB?

Tags: wiring, cables, conductors

I need to feed a 45 kVA transformer and I need to use an LB to pull the conductors through. Will I have issues with the bend radius of the 2/0 conductors? It's a 3C cable. the conduit is  1-1/2" HUB size Metal LB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IPC-A-620 minimum bend radius for insulated wire (not jacketed cable) is 2x the diameter of the wire (including insulation).  2/0 wire is about 0.6" insulation diameter so you *should* be fine but the wire manufacturer's datasheet is the overriding document.